# How to research a Victorian company

Tags: victorian, business-history

In June 1890, the **South Atlantic (African) Land and Exploration Company** advertised its prospectus in a number of English papers including the Brighton Gazette. I am endeavouring to find out as much as I can about the fate of this company, but I can find very little.

The Truth magazine, for July 3 1890, reports on the prospectus sceptically.

> "I am really at a loss to understand what sort of person (assuming him to be of sane mind) would pay £ 125,000 for the privilege to expend £ 25,000in exploring and prospecting the territories of Hendricks, chief of the Veldschoendragers."

But that's about it. Matters are made more difficult by the number of companies of similar name and avowed aim that existed in this period.

Where can I research this further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A search through archive of [The Gazette (London)](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/all-notices/London/notice?results-page-size=10&categorycode-all=all&numberOfLocationSearches=1&start-publish-date=1889-01-01&location-distance-1=1&text=South%20Atlantic%20Land%20and%20Exploration%20Company&end-publish-date=1895-12-31), Official Public Record for the U.K., turns up:

1. [22 November 1892; Issue:26347, Page:6589 & 6591:](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/26347/page/6591)

> [image]
>
> [image]

2. [9 May 1893; Issue:26399, Page:2692 & 4](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/London/issue/26399/page/2694)

> [image: ,,,]
>
> [image]

So the company was dissolved as of May 9, 1893, for failing to respond to the notice of intent to dissolve published 22 November, 1892. There is no asterix on either posting, so no company of an identical name was known to be operating.

Comment: Thanks so much. I suspected something similar might have happened, probably, I guess after they failed to get the investment they were hoping for.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong: They weren't alone, as noted by the long list of other companies dissolved at the same time and even in the same Gazette editions.